# Managing dependencies in a JAR - Test Automation

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jar, dependencies

I'm not sure if this is the best place to post such a question, but here it is. I'm a test automation engineer that works primarily with backend, spring boot command line apps. My tests, at a high level, are designed to ensure that any type of data that is thrown at the app will be handled correctly. We are a Java shop.

As with any "good" testing practice, I am treating the app like a blackbox, in that I do not pull in the model objects to run my tests. I simply supply the app with data, execute a command line type script (run.sh) that takes my data and processes it. My tests are comprised mostly of JDBC (to interact with the database) and a slew of ArrayList utilities that I have put together to sort out result sets and get specific db information.

Thus far, I have been deploying my tests as a JAR. I bundle everything up and deploy it to the environment with a script that will execute the tests. The tests do not run when the app is run. Though they do live inside of the project, they are a separate entity with separate launcher classes. However, I am finding that managing dependencies in a JAR is a real headache. Is there a better way to deploy automation / integration tests for command line apps?

I'm pulling in maven shade plugin to bundle all of my dependencies into a "God JAR", but that isn't helping me to resolve the issues that occur when I attempt to execute the JAR. I get multiple bean instantiation errors, relating to the app itself, and not my tests. For this reason, I pull in the app model, and the app itself as dependencies. When I ran the tests in my initial testing, they worked just fine. Deployed to environment and they continued to work correctly. Fast forward a couple of months, a few changes made to the app, and now it's a dependency nightmare when I build the new JAR.

TLDR: I'm having trouble managing dependencies in a maven project, integration tests JAR. Is there a better way to deploy automation / integration tests for command line apps where dependency management is easier?

(Note: I'm relatively new to this world, so pardon me if the question seems a bit vague).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
Please
take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and
read through the [help center](/help), in particular
[How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic).
I think https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for this question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error happens when you use the shade plugin to re-package the spring boot jar. The way spring boot works is to add dependencies into the jar as jars itself and configure its own class loader (in the meta config) that is capable of reading classes from jar files inside the jar file. The standard java class loader does not do this - thats probably why the shade plugin misses out some jars (probably the ones embedded in the spring boot uber jar).

what I would try is to create a test-version of the spring boot app that contains the test-classes in the compile scope and a dependency to the original spring boot jar (you don't need the uber jar - therefore you may have to add a [classifier](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html#classifier) to the original (app) spring boot plugin config to have that jar still available as it is replaced by default) and use the [spring boot plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html) to package the test version of it (using the dependency and its classifier above you used for the original app).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I initially used it to try and prevent the error, but once I pulled it out of the pom, I was only seeing a couple of errors which are caused by our enterprise config. Should have done this sooner lol. Thanks.